# Adding info to MySQL not working

Tags: python, mysql, database, row

Made quite a few questions already relating to this project, but I'm having too much trouble with it and I'm getting grey hairs trying to figure it out.

Using Python and Scrapy to get web info.
I can add each of the 3 items (Title, CriticalScore, UserScore) to the database seperatley fine, using this code:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ps3 (userscore) VALUES (%s)",[item['uscore']])
```

Now that works fine, it puts them in ascending ROWS and its all good.
However, I need to add Title, CriticalScore and UserScore to the same row, and when I try it, I get this error:

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQ
L syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near \'),("\'60\'",),("\'4.9\'",))\' at line 1')
```

And I get that error using this line of code:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ps3 (titles, criticalscore, userscore) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",[item['title'],item['cscore'],item['uscore']])
```

I've been on the Stack Overflow Python chat and nobody could figure it out unfortunately.
If it is any help this is how I create the table:

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE ps3 
    (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Title text, CriticalScore text, UserScore text)''')
```

Really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Try stripping single quotes: `[item['title'].strip("'"),item['cscore'].strip("'"),item['uscore'].strip("'")]`. Looks like you don't need them in the database.

Comment: probably you have single quotes in titles, you need to escape single quotes by 2 single quotes, like `item['title'].replace("'", "''")`

Comment: @alecxe When I use strip() it says list object has no attribute 'strip

Comment: @behzad.nouri That didn't work unfortunatley, same error as with alecxe, doesnt work on a list item :S

Comment: @AndyOHart yeah, this is the problem then. You probably need to get the 0th item from the lists, e.g.: `item['title'][0]`. Looks like this needs to be done inside the scrapy spider's parse function. Probably you have that `extract()` call that returns a list. You need to get 0th item from it.

Comment: what does `item['title'],item['cscore'],item['uscore']` look like? also try `... VALUES ('{}',{},{})'.format(item['title'].replace("'", "''"), item['cscore'], item['uscore'])`. note `'{}'`; strings should be quoted in sql commans

Comment: @behzad.nouri well, strictly speaking it's a bad idea to pass query parameters via direct formatting - parameters are not escaped in this case.

Comment: @alecxe based on error he gets, apparently they are not escaped any ways

Comment: @alecxe Yeah your right that makes sense. However I keep getting out of bounds errors when I try it. I only allow certain information in so I have an if statement, and i increment a variable every time it goes into the if, as these are the only allowed items, and I use that variable however it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @alecxe actually just tried it and it worked, didn't know that by setting it to 0 it would constantly  increment anyway, thanks, you should convert it to an answer so I can select it man!

Comment: @AndyOHart great! But consider making the spider do this getting 0th item from extracted lists, so that your item fields would contain strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what should work:

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        ps3 
        (titles, criticalscore, userscore) 
    VALUES 
        (%s,%s,%s)""",
    [item['title'][0] if item['title'] else '',
     item['cscore'][0] if item['cscore'] else '',
     item['uscore'][0] if item['uscore'] else ''])
```

But, instead of doing it in the pipeline, you'd better make it inside the scrapy spider, there you are extracting the data.

Comment: Worked great, didn't know that [0] would increment the rows and everything, basically i didnt know how scrapy or python was working with the items and all. thanks for this